# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: channel.createWebhook is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my `setuplogger.js` file, and the bottom part is the code I have in my `index.js`. This code is supposed to create a webhook for the channel set as the logschannel, this webhook will send logs for every ban that happens in the guild. But the problem is that I keep getting the .createWebhook is not a function, I couldn't figure out how to fix this error so I just came here.

```
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            return message.channel.send(`***Error:*** *You do not have* ***[ADMINISTRATOR]*** *permission.*`);
        }

        const logEnableDisable = args[0];
        const logChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();

        if (!logEnableDisable) {
            return message.channel.send(`***Error:*** *${prefix}setuplogger <enable/disable> <channel>*`)
        }

        if (!logChannel) {
            return message.channel.send(`***Error:*** *${prefix}setuplogger <enable/disable> <channel>*`)
        }

        if (logEnableDisable === 'enable') {
            db.set(`${message.guild.id}_logChannel`, logChannel.id)
            message.channel.send(`*Succesfully enabled logs to* ***${logChannel}.***`)
        }

        if (logEnableDisable === 'disable') {
            const findLogchannel = db.get(`${message.guild.id}_logChannel`);
            if (!findLogchannel) {
                message.channel.send(`***Error:*** *Log channel has not been setup yet, use \`${prefix}setuplogger enable <channel>\`.*`)
            } else {
                db.delete(`${message.guild.id}_logChannel`, true)
                message.channel.send(`*Succesfully removed logs from* ***${logChannel}.***`)
            }
        }
    }
}

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

client.on("guildBanAdd", async (guild, user) => {
      const channel = db.get(`${guild.id}_logChannel`);

      const fetchedLogs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: "MEMBER_BAN_ADD",
      });

      const banLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

      if(!banLog) return console.log("It doesn't work.")

      const { executor, target } = banLog;

      if (target.id === user.id) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Ban')
          .setDescription(`**User Banned**\fModerator: ${executor}\fUser: ${target.tag}`)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setColor(color);
        channel.createWebhook('Logger', { avatar: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-circle/512/notepad_note_wrrte_pencil-512.png' }).then(webhook => { webhook.send(embed) });
      }
    });
```

Comment: The error is very clear, `channel.createWebhook` is not a function...

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: My discord version is ^12.5.3.

Comment: "The error is very clear, channel.createWebhook is not a function..." 
ye i do realize that, but why.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're saving the channel's ID in the database (`logChannel.id`) and later, you're trying to call the `createWebhook` method on a string, not the channel. If you call a non-existing method on a string you'll receive an error; *"channel.createWebhook is not a function"*:

```js
const channel = '86924931458913231434'
const webhook = channel.createWebhook('Logger')
```

To solve this, you need to fetch the channel first so you can use the [`createWebhook`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createWebhook) method:

```js
client.on('guildBanAdd', async (guild, user) => {
  const channelID = db.get(`${guild.id}_logChannel`);

  if (!channelID) return console.log('No channel ID');

  try {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelID);

    const fetchedLogs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({
      limit: 1,
      type: 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD',
    });

    const banLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

    if (!banLog) return console.log("It doesn't work.");

    const { executor, target } = banLog;

    if (target.id === user.id) {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Ban')
        .setDescription(
          `**User Banned**\fModerator: ${executor}\fUser: ${target.tag}`,
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor(color);

      const webhook = await channel.createWebhook('Logger', {
        avatar:
          'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-circle/512/notepad_note_wrrte_pencil-512.png',
      });
      webhook.send(embed);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```